# Trigger a PubSub message from Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, firebase-admin

Firebase docs mention a straightforward way of subscribing to a pubSub topic.

Does Cloud Functions or Firebase Admin SDK provide a way to publish pubSub events or we are limited to what is described in Google Cloud Platform docs: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#pubsub-publish-message-nodejs

Comment: Did you solve your question? I'm trying to do the same and can't figure out how to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase Admin SDK, for many products, is just a convenience wrapper around the underlying Cloud SDKs.  For pubsub, however, it provides no such wrapper.  You'll have to use the Google Cloud SDK directly if you want to send pubsub messages.

Comment: I think the author of the question meant to ask how to **publish** to a Pub/Sub from a Cloud Function, not how to subscribe to a Pub/Sub.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it can help, although it's late. Here is a clear explanation (by Google itself) on how to use it https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher and here is an example https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/blob/master/samples/publishMessageWithCustomAttributes.js

TLDR
Here is my condensed version

```
public static publishMessage(data: unknown, topicName: string): Observable<void> {
        const pubSubClient: PubSub = new PubSub();
        const dataBuffer: Buffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data));
        return from(pubSubClient.topic(topicName).publish(dataBuffer));
}
```